# WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx sometimes failed?

Tags: rdp

I have a rdp plugin used in my C# AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting rdp client:

```
rdp.AdvancedSettings8.PluginDlls = "{7d413ce8-a0a1-42d9-a67b-6d4be4af17c5}";
```

When I open the channel on server side:

```
channelHandle = Win32API.WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(Win32API.WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
        Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(APP_CHANNEL_NAME),
        Win32API.WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION_DYNAMIC | 4);
```

Sometimes ok, sometimes failed with error code = 0x31, no more error description. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: The user disconnects and reconnects, attempting to reopen the channel.
errCode = 0x31 ErrMessage = 连接到系统上的设备没有发挥作用
A few users have this phenomenon. Their operating systems are Windows 10 and Windows 7.
What is the cause of the failure to open the channel? Can I get more detailed error information?